# using andorid apps with wi-fi with paid providers which require log-in

Tags: android

You know there are internet providers that require log in though a website. Most common examples are the coffee shops, or airport points, or hotels.
It's ok for your laptop because you can use a browser and you are done, but what if you wanted to use your android apps in your phone? how you set the auth data to them?

does anybody knows an app which will allow me to do that? e.g. set the needed auth to let the rest of the apps run without a problem..  I'm thinking of a proxy but not sure if it is what i need here..

thanks!

Comment: Are you sure Android doesn't handle this itself? I know my iPhone pops up a browser window with the login page when I connect to one of those types of wi-fi networks.

Comment: As far as I remember, every time I encountered an internet connection that requires a login/pass, I just opened my android's web browser, logged in and after that, all applications that requires internet access worked well.

Answer (score 3):

The way those authentication points work is that most traffic through the access point are dropped until the user opens their browser.  The browser's HTTP request is ignored and the gateway page is displayed instead, and once the user accepts the terms of service, or pays, or whatever, the packet filter is disabled for your device.

This means that an app that's authenticated to the hotspot can run any kind of application over the network without the application being aware of the hotspot's specific security model. However, it does mean that you'd need to put a browser in your app and use some fairly fuzzy logic to determine when to show it.

Most of the time, the user will know when he or she is using this type of provider and will know to login through the android browser first.